# Maven release plugin executes tests twice

Tags: maven, junit

When release:clean release:prepare release:perform is executed , the tests are executed twice

Once at release:prepare , stage run-preparation-goals , task clean verify

And another time on release:perform ,stage run-perform-goals , task deploy

Is there any configuration option to make tests run only on first one and not being executed on perform?

BR

Yulian Oifa

Answer (score 2):

That's because 2 full builds are run as part of the commands you issue.

The release:prepare section performs lots of checks on the code & repository, and does a full build to ensure all tests pass.

The release:perform section tags the repo, then pulls that tag. It performs a build *based on that tag* and the releases that build to your artefact store of choice (Nexus/Artifactory/wherever).

These steps are designed this way to ensure you don't pollute your repo with a tag on code that doesn't build, and tests are an integral part of your build. Once maven is happy your code is good to go, it creates the tag, and pulls it so it knows for sure that the code being released is the code referenced by the tag, and nothing else. Building that tag for release requires a full build, including the tests.

You can skip the tests on one or other of the steps, or on both, but you're missing the point of tests, and of the release plugin, if you do that.

Comment: Hi, I do understand that in case release:prepare and release perform are executed separately there may be code change between them. However since both are running as single execution on jenkins effectively there is no reason to have tests running twice , because its same code , on prepare jenkins runs the tests modifes the poms and prepares a tag , while on release it is pushing the artifacts to nexus repository. 
Therefore i think it would be best to disable the tests on release stage to decrease the job executions time ( some projects we have are running tests for hours )

Comment: It's your code, so you can do whatever you wish with it. I don't agree with you, but that's of no import here. I'd point out, though, that if your tests are running for hours, there's something wrong with your test approach. You should look at dividing them into better phases and running them at appropriate stages of your lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `goals` parameter and add `-DskipTests=true`.

This parameter will skip the tests only on the `perform` part.

Comment: Hi.
The test are still being executed when i add -DskipTests=true
The full maven command is
mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -DskipTests=true release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${releaseVersion} -DdevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion}

Comment: That is not what I suggested. I suggested to change the `goals` parameter, i.e. add something like `-Dgoals="clean verify -DskipTests"`

Answer (score 1):

Eventually i had to change a logic.

I have executed mvn clean install release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Pmaven-release

and create a maven-release. As result the tests are executed only at install

BR

Yulian Oifa

```
<profile>
        <id>maven-release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>                         
                        <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip</arguments>                        
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>        
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip running the tests (managed by surefire plugin) with an explicitly specified parameter `-DskipTests`:

Something like this:

```
mvn release:perform -DskipTests
```

For intergration tests (managed by failsafe plugin) you can use a similar flag: `-DskipITs`

If you don't want even compile the tests you can use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` (for both unit and integration tests)

Comment: This would cancel a tests in both release:prepare and release perform , the goal is to have tests executed exactly once

Comment: I've barely used release plugin, but in general: you're running two separate commands, `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`, right? If so I'm suggesting to run -`DskipTests` only with the "perform" goal: "`mvn release:prepare` " and then "`mvn release:performa -DskipTests`"

Comment: Nope, i am running them as single command through jenkins CI. so the full command is mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform